# Google API is not working properly on Magento 2

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

We actually work with Magento 2.2.1 and have placed all information into the fields in Stores->Configuration->Sales->Google API. But if we check with Chrome Tag Assistant we get a message "Same web property ID is tracked twice." for Google Analytics.
The AdWords conversion does not work at all. No conversion will be tracked.

Anybody who can help?

Comment: Just upgraded from 2.1.0 to 2.2.2 and analytics started reporting zero bounce rate. I noticed some problems with conversion tracking too. Definitely there is a bug in the google analytics module.

Comment: We are having issues with the Google API module being set to "off"/"disabled"/"no" on Staging and Production. We are deploying to the Cloud infrastructure using the new Web UI deploy with `staging` and `production` branches, and I just noticed this in the documentation which might be the cause of our problem: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/cloud/trouble/trouble-google-analytics-deploy.html